# Windows 10 Dual Boot Ubuntu from Dell Restore USB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, dell-inspiron

I have a dell computer that and downloaded the USB installation recovery.

I do not see a simply "Install Windows" option like I am used to with Windows 7. Instead I get a blue screen with big tiles and the only options appear to be to recover windows from the thumb drive.

When I do this, it restores the machine exactly to factory state and does not give me an option to only use half the hard drive during the windows installation. When the default is installed the entire hard drive is used for the windows install.

How can I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu from using a Dell USB restore drive.

Comment: Need some clarity here: 1) what is presently installed on the hard drive ? only windows? only ubuntu ? or nothing ? 2) what is on the 'Dell USB'  inferring from the flow of the question it would appear to be Windows 10 3) From Windows you are not gonna see that option natively on most install/restore media as it is not deemed ( by MS ) as a default or common consumer common option.  4) Assuming either that Windows 10 is on the hard drive or the USB which of the 9 (18 total assuming both 32/64 bit)  is in play?

Answer (score 0):

Your USB drive for Windows will not give you the option to dual boot, as Windows is the dominating OS in its own mind. Once you've created your Windows OS, it would be necessary to partition the drive (or use your Linux installer) to make space for the dual boot.

It appears that you've completed the Windows OS install. Download a boot image for your flavor of Ubuntu and note the prompts for sizing the Linux partition and creating dual boot. Don't select "use entire hard drive" for obvious reasons.

Your last question (without a question mark) has the answer of "you cannot." It is a two step process.